# WARNING hook before_worker_boot failed with exception (Redis::CannotConnectError) getaddrinfo_a: System error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, redis, puma

I keep getting this error while trying to start rails in docker.

2023-02-15 13:42:52 [54] WARNING hook before_worker_boot failed with exception (Redis::CannotConnectError) getaddrinfo_a: System error
2023-02-15 13:42:52 [55] WARNING hook before_worker_boot failed with exception (Redis::CannotConnectError) getaddrinfo_a: System error
2023-02-15 13:42:52 [51] WARNING hook before_worker_boot failed with exception (Redis::CannotConnectError) getaddrinfo_a: System error

("GET /csc108/admin" - (172.27.0.1)): #<Redis::CannotConnectError: getaddrinfo_a: System error>

However, it worked for a few times with the same procedure.

I tried to rebuild the image and restart the container

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.